# Disable image compression on Chrome browser in Android

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using background Image by applying below css on main body element in my UI.

```
.homepage-bg {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: url("@{imagePath}/homepage/bg.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* pour anciens Chrome et Safari */
    background-size: cover; /* version standardisée */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

> I am facing issue of image compression on Chrome browser on Android devices. (Works fine in firefox)

I have searched on internet regarding this and found some solution like applying `pagespeed_no_transform` but it didn't worked for me.

I am attaching screenshots of chrome (Not working) and firefox (Working)

[image: Chrome]

[image]

Any help please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I tried adding `min-height:<SOME GOOD VALUE>` (Ex. 600px, 800px) And now the image is stretched to whole page. (ScreenShot Attached below)

[image]

> My question is why i can't simply apply `min-height: 100%` in which
>   image should take full height?

Comment: something like this ? just take away fixed in background. https://www.bootply.com/WOw6MKBis2

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after doing some troubleshooting, below css done the trick for me.

> min-height: 100vh;